# Display results of AJAX / PHP poll on initial page load + after voting

Tags: php, html, ajax

Using w3school's PHP / AJAX poll example, I'm curious how it could be modified so that the results of the poll are displayed on the initial page load in addition to updating once a user has selected their poll choice. The page with the code is here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp. I've also copied it below:

HTML FILE:

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
function getVote(int)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="poll">
<h3>Do you like PHP and AJAX so far?</h3>
<form>
Yes:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
<br>No:
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0)
  {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
  }
if ($vote == 1)
  {
  $no = $no + 1;
  }

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

TEXT FILE:

```
0||0
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML (edit line):

```
<body onload="readVote();">
```

JS (add to code):

```
function readVote()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
    document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote_read.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP (new file, the name is "poll_vote_read.php"):

```
//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I think this will work but I didn't test it out, vote up if it works!